# flash as3 - how to get next element in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array of five possible videos that can play called videos, and an array of active videos called activeVideos. When one video finishes playing, I need to take its index, find its location in the activeVideos array, and get the next value in the array. If there are no more values in the array, I need to grab the first value. So essentially:

```
activeVideos = [0,1,3]
videos = [video1, video2, video3];

function nextVideo(e:Event){
    var curIndex = videos.indexOf(currentVideo);
    var next = activeVideos.find(curIndex).nextValue // pseudo-code - need to locate the position of the current video within the active array, select the next element, and call show video.
    showVideo(videos[next]);
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function nextVideo(e:Event){
    var curIndex = videos.indexOf(currentVideo) + 1;
    var nextVideo = curIndex >= videos.length ? videos[0] : videos[curIndex];
    showVideo(nextVideo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
activeVideos = [0,1,3]
videos = [video1, video2, null, video3];

function nextVideo(e:Event){
    var curIndex = videos.indexOf(currentVideo);
    var next = activeVideos[curIndex+1] || activeVideos[0];
    showVideo(videos[next]);
}
```

Comment: umm, wouldn't this assign a boolean value to next?

Comment: || in Ecma works like it does in ruby if nil is returned in the assignment it moves on to the next assignment. since an out of range index would return nil we move on to the next statement past or until we are returned a non nil or non undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this at home, I must confess my flash might be a bit rusty since the advent of the html5, css3 + js hype :)

```
nextIndex = -1;
nextIndex = ( (curIndex+1 == videos.length) ? 0 : curIndex+1 );
if (nextIndex > -1){
  var next = activeVideos[nextIndex];
  // ... do your stuff 
}
```